# Is it possible to link to draft pages?

Tags: links, draft

Problem: I have a overview-page with a sub-page. Both pages are still in status "draft". Now I want to create a link on the overview-page to the sub-page, a popup appears, but in the list of internal pages, the drafted pages do not appear.

1. Do I need to publish the sub-pages first to be able to link to them, or is there another way?
2. Why are they not appearing in the list of internal pages?

Answer (score 4):

I should start off by saying that linking to drafts will **only work for logged in users** (with appropriate permissions) - other users will simply hit a 404 Not Found!

You'd be much better off getting all your content **ready & published**, or only link to it **once it *is* ready**!

Nevertheless, to answer your question, to link to a draft simply enter the URL manually in the **URL** field (as opposed to searching for the page using the link feature).

[image: WordPress link visual editor]

It'll probably be something like `http://example.com/?page_id=X&preview=true` - you can find it beneath the title field when editing.

> Why are [drafts] not appearing in the list of internal pages?

The very nature of the WordPress 'link to content' feature is to ease the process mentioned above. It only shows *published* content, as this almost *always* what you want to link to (rather than cluttering up the results with drafts, revisions etc.).

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment. I'm starting to write a tutorial with several pages. It would be nice to set up the hierarchy before publishing,...

Comment: I would like to downvote this, but I don't have enough points. I've been drafting a lot of pages and posts, I intend to publish them altogether. Not being able to link to them is a lot of work and chicken or the egg scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question (12+ years), but I don't think it was adequately answered. The best solution for the situation the OP asked about is to simply link to the post ID for each draft article.

As soon as you save a draft, it is assigned an ID. You'll see this ID number in all URLs related to that post, such as when editing the post. When editing the post, it will have a URI like this: `https://example.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=13985`

Let's say the draft post ID is `13985`, you can link to that ID using the following URI:  `https://example.net/?p=13985`.

These links will continue to work even after the draft is published.

Obviously, it's important to ensure you publish all the drafts you've linked to.